# How to programatically find out the last login time to a machine?

Tags: c#, authentication, monitoring

I would like to a) programatically and b) remotely find out the last date/time that a user successfully logged into a Windows machine (via remote desktop or at the console). I would be willing to take any typical windows language (C, C#, VB, batch files, JScript, etc...) but any solution would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
  public static DateTime? GetLastLogin(string domainName,string userName)
  {
        PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,domainName);
        UserPrincipal uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c, userName);
        return uc.LastLogon;
   }
```

You will need to add references to using using System.DirectoryServices and 
 System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

EDIT: You might be able to get the last login Datetime to a specific machine by doing something like this:

```
 public static DateTime? GetLastLoginToMachine(string machineName, string userName)
 {
        PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName);
        UserPrincipal uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c, userName);
        return uc.LastLogon;

 }
```

Comment: Does that give the last login to the domain, or to the computer it is run on?

Comment: Good question.MSDN says this: "Gets the Nullable DateTime that specifies the date and time of the last logon for this account."
I'm guessing that this is based on whether the ContextType is set to Domain or Machine but I can't verify this since I'm running on a standalone machine but an my educated guess is that if you are running on a domain it probably the last successful logon for that account on the domain.

Comment: Darn, I like both of your answers, but I really need the last login time of a specific user to the specified computer.

Comment: I think I might have found a way, I've edited my answer. Again I can't verify this since I'm not on a domain.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DirectoryServices to do this in C#:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

        DirectoryEntry dirs = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
        foreach (DirectoryEntry de in dirs.Children)
        {
            if (de.SchemaClassName == "User")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(de.Name);
                if (de.Properties["lastlogin"].Value != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["lastlogin"].Value.ToString());
                }
                if (de.Properties["lastlogoff"].Value != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["lastlogoff"].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Great answer, any chance you would know how to modify it to include domain users such as MYDOMAIN or at least a specific domain user such as MYDOMAIN\MYUSER?

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I managed to put together a nice PowerShell script which takes in a computer name and lists out the accounts and <s>the **ACTUAL** last logon on the specific computer.</s> ... TURNS OUT MICROSOFT NEVER PROGRAMMED THIS FUNCTION CORRECTLY, IT TRIES TO GET LOGON INFORMATION FROM ACTIVE DIRECTORY AND STORE IT LOCALLY, SO YOU HAVE USERS LOG INTO OTHER MACHINES AND IT'LL UPDATE THE LOGIN DATES ON YOUR MACHINE, BUT THEY NEVER LOGGED INTO YOUR MACHINE.... COMPLETE FAILURE!

```
$REMOTEMACHINE = "LoCaLhOsT"

$NetLogs = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $REMOTEMACHINE
foreach ($NetLog in $NetLogs) 
{ 
  if($NetLog.LastLogon)
  {
    $LastLogon = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($NetLog.LastLogon)
    if($LastLogon -ne [DateTime]::MinValue)
    {
      Write-Host $NetLog.Name ' - ' $LastLogon
    }
  }
}
```

Note:  From what I can gather, the Win32_NetworkLoginProfile is using the "Win32API|Network Management Structures|USER_INFO_3" structure.  So the C# equivalent would be to pInvoke [NetUserEnum] with the level specifying the structures returned in the buffer if you wanted to avoid using WMI.

Fun Fact:  The DateTime is returned as an Int32 through USER_INFO_3 structure, so when it's the year 2038, the date will no longer be correct once integer overflow occurs.... #UnixMillenniumBug

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `CMD`:

```
C:\Windows\System32>query user /server:<yourHostName>
```

OR (shorter)

```
C:\Windows\System32>quser /server:<yourHostName>
```

Output will be something like this:

```
USERNAME    SESSIONNAME    ID    STATE    LOGONTIME
userXYZ     console         1    Active   19.01.2017 08:59
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using pInvoke for "RegQueryInfoKey" in C# to retrieve LastWriteTime on the registry key of each profile located under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176943/7354452

Comment: Why would you need to use P/Invoke just to read from the Registry? .NET provides managed access to the Registry.

Comment: Also, on my machine I don't see `LastWriteTime` being populated for any accounts, which suggests that it's not a reliable method. This is a domain account on Windows 10.