# How to get the Windows user's login time?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way in C# to get the time when the current user logged in?

A command called quser in command prompt will list some basic information about current users, including LOGON TIME.

Is there a System property or something I can access in c# which I can get the user's login time from?

I am getting username by Environment.UserName property. Need the login time.

I've tried this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

Console.WriteLine("Login Time: {0}",GetLastLoginToMachine(Environment .MachineName , Environment.UserName));
public static DateTime? GetLastLoginToMachine(string machineName, string userName)
{
    PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName);
    UserPrincipal uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c, userName);
    return uc.LastLogon;
}
```

Got the following errors:

[image: Visual Studio build errors]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475066/6356434

Comment: @Nicholas using System.DirectoryServices; 

 The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Raised the question again since that version is too old

Comment: Have you added the reference to System.DirectoryServices to your project?

Comment: @DanielHollinrake 
I have added and got errors that the DirectoryServices does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Comment: Which .Net version you have selected in Project Properties? If you are using "Client" version of the libraries, you may have some problems - in that case, try switching your project to "full" framework.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl If I change my .NET version in the project properties then my other components will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include the reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

[image: References Manager]

Then you can do this to get the last logon time:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static DateTime? GetLastLoginToMachine(string machineName, string userName)
{
    PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName);
    UserPrincipal uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c, userName);
    return uc.LastLogon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Added a reference in the solution explorer System.DirectoryServices .

Comment: @quetzalcoatl go easy on him mate. It's probably embarrassingly obvious to him now. Certainly a hard-learnt lesson!

Comment: @DanielHollinrake: you're right.. re-reading it now some time after, I was probably too harsh, and it wasn't necessary at all. thanks!

Comment: @DanielHollinrake It is never an embarrassment to learn anything new. Am rather glad you guys took out time for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the LastUserLogon time from the following namespace.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Try

```
DateTime? CurrentUserLoggedInTime = UserPrincipal.Current.LastLogon;
```

You can get the account information as well :

```
string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
string machineName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query WMI:

```cs
// using System.Management;

private static Dictionary<string, DateTime> getMachineLogonName(string machine)
{
    var loggedOnUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();


    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", machine));

    SelectQuery sessionQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_LogonSession");

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher sessionSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, sessionQuery))
    using (ManagementObjectCollection sessionMOs = sessionSearcher.Get())
    {

        foreach (var sessionMO in sessionMOs)
        {
            // Interactive sessions
            if ((UInt32)sessionMO.Properties["LogonType"].Value == 2)
            {
                var logonId = (string)sessionMO.Properties["LogonId"].Value;
                var startTimeString = (string)sessionMO.Properties["StartTime"].Value;
                var startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startTimeString.Substring(0, 21), "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                WqlObjectQuery userQuery = new WqlObjectQuery(@"ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogonSession.LogonId='" + logonId + @"'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser");

                using (var userSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, userQuery))
                using (var userMOs = userSearcher.Get())
                {
                    var username = userMOs.OfType<ManagementObject>().Select(u => (string)u.Properties["Name"].Value).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (!loggedOnUsers.ContainsKey(username))
                    {
                        loggedOnUsers.Add(username, startTime);
                    }
                    else if(loggedOnUsers[username]> startTime)
                    {
                        loggedOnUsers[username] = startTime;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return loggedOnUsers;
}
```

Then just call the method with target machine name:

```cs
var logins = getMachineLogonName(".");
```

Comment: And is it possible to get windows password? I guess that would be a security issue.

Comment: @KuharanBhowmik, that would be a serious security issue. There are methods for changing the password, but not retrieving it.