# C# Get currently logged in users logged in time in .net forms application

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get the Windows login time for the current user.

I am using a Windows .NET Form. Nothing I've found works. The time that I end up getting is the LAST login time and not the latest login time which makes no sense. Seems to me that Microsoft broke this function but what do i know.

I have already tried all methods on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480492/how-to-get-the-windows-users-login-time?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C43.2480) and still not the right times. I started a new thread as to not resurrect a dead thread but I may be wrong for doing this. Sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I have to propose this as an answer.

Have you tried running the tool wiser in the manner suggested here?

[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Inside here you can capture the output and parse it.

```
    private List<string> RunCommand(string exeName, string args, string folder)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName);

        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = folder;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = args;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        var results = new List<string>();
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            results.Add(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Above is the code I use.

Apologies for formatting as I am doing this on my phone

Answer (score 1):

The current user is

```
  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

But there is no Login-Time stored, and your approach sounds strange.

If someone starts your Application 5 days after Windows was started, you want to logout the user from windows, because he logged in more then 45min ago ? I hope I misunderstand this.

You just have to track the time your application is running. It's a single-user application, you can shut down your application at any time, if you like.

Comment: Yes, you talk about the windows login, somebody logs in to windows, and 5 days later your start your application. You do not talk about a web application, where you first start the application and then you login. You first login, and after that you start the application. You mix-up Login to Windows and login to a single application. You cannot start anything at login to windows, cause your WinForms application is not running.

Comment: @xCONFLiCTiONx Your question did not include the word Service. A Windows-Service is the correct approach, a Service runs before the user logs in. But a Service is never a WinForms-application, it has no user-interface. For my understanding you wanted to use a user-application like Microsoft Word to log off from Windows - that was just confusing. Windows-Login is always the first thing a user does - starting an application always comes later, endless time later, can be days later.